# An error prevented me from creating the final rig with rigify + pichipoi addon

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I'm trying to use the **rigify + pitchipoi** in combination with the **makewalk** addon because I want to make the retargeting of a **BVH file**. So I cutted the bones of the **METARIG armature** that are responsible for the movements of the breasts (because otherwise it did not work) and then I loaded a **BVH file** with the **makewalk** addon and it has been accepted. Problem arose when I tried to create the final rig because there was an error that stopped my ambitions of glory...

[image: error]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tz-VKLcysfhE15hh44PLEH78SEDmwOFD) you can find the blender file before pressing on "**generate rig**".